# Python - set comprehension difference between w and w[0]

Tags: python, set

I'm going through a basic set comprehension. I have this

```
words = set('zbcdedg')

first_letters = set()
```

Then I'm setting up a set comprehension

```
first_letters = {w for w in words}
```

Yet, this one does the same trick

```
first_letters = {w[0] for w in words}
```

What is the difference between the 2? Why use the latter than the first or vice-versa?

Comment: There is no difference between a single-character string (`w`) and the first character of that string (`w[0]`).

Comment: Just `w` is preferable because it's shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: `{w for w in words}` is going to give you  the same as `words = set('zbcdedg')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w` is a single-character string. The first character in a single-character string just so happens to be equal to the string. You can do `w[0][0][0][0][0]...` if you want and it'll still be the same. Use the shortest, most readable version: just `w` in this case.

Comment: Hi @tigerhawkt3, many thanks for your answer. one additional question if you do not mind: I did try with `w[1]` and I had `string index out of range`. Why ?

Comment: @AndyK because a single character string doesn't have a second character?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got a better grasp now. Cheers matey